# What is the regular expression to check empty XML nodes?

Tags: regex

I get an xml node;

```
<p:FirstAddressLine1></p:FirstAddressLine1>
```

I want to rewrite that node, if it has an empty string/null. I used `^$` but it fails to validate that particular xml node contains empty string.

Anyone knows , what im doing wrong here? and the right regular expression to be used?

Comment: What language are you writing in? Show us the code snippet that you using to match.

Comment: Why you didn't test if it has one character (at least): `.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i need to test xml nodes come with empty. Then i want to add some default values.

Comment: @merlin2011 i'm using an Java based application server, it will support regular expressions when we provide in the configuration file. So, here i provide particular expression, but seems failing. The underlying language is java

Comment: @Ratha, Is the match supposed to be against the inside of the tag?

Comment: My idea is to test if there is one character at least, instead of testing if there is no character at all.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte checking for one character  perfectly works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @merlin2011 didnt get you. But i found solution as CasmiretHippolyte said

Comment: However, be careful with newlines that don't match the dot. Use the dotall mode if possible, or the javascript trick `[\s\S]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the following `regex`

```
(?:<p:FirstAddressLine1>(?!<\/p))
```

Is uses a `Negative Lookahead`, and will match `<p:FirstAddressLine1>` followed by anything other then `</p`. If it sees a `</p` directly after the first <> it will not match the string.

**EXAMPLE USAGE**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = <DATA>;

foreach (@lines) {

    if ( $_ =~ m/(?:<p:FirstAddressLine1>(?!<\/p))/ ) {
        print "The string is NOT empty\n";

    }
    else {
        print "The string is empty\n";
    }

}

__DATA__
<p:FirstAddressLine1></p:FirstAddressLine1>
<p:FirstAddressLine1>TEST</p:FirstAddressLine1>
```

**RESULT**

```
The string is empty
The string is NOT empty
```

Comment: Im not directly using java. Im configuring an Appserver which is java based